# Who is the physically strongest villain, All for One or Muscular?

Tags: my-hero-academia

In the battle with Izuku, Muscular was able to "cause destruction on a similar scale to Izuku's 100% Detroit Smash. He was also able to directly overpower Izuku, who was using One For All 100% at the time, in a physical clash." 
In the other hand, in the last battle of All for One with All Might, All For One says he is now confident of trading punches with All Might with his new strenght augmentation quirks, and he does indeed.

Who is supposed to be the physically strongest villain, All for One or Muscular? Does the manga give more info about their strenghts?

Answer (score 1):

I would like to start with this: In his fight with Muscular, Izuku was not using One For All with 100%. That was just Izuku with 100%.

We saw the glimpse of All Might's power with his fight against first Nomu in season one. That Nomu was designed for him however All Might was still able to defeat Nomu.

Now if we think about those we can say that All Might could have defeat Muscular which is defeated by Izuku that can't even use OfA with its full extent.

Comment: I dont understand what is the difference with "Izuku not using One for All 100%" and "Izuku with 100%". Izuku can indeed use One for All 100% but breaking his body, can he? Or am I mistaken about this?

Comment: Izuku can't use OfA with its full power. He also a limit because of his body. Think about like this. You have a fragile cap. You want to fill it with water. It can take 200mL but it's risky since that much can break the cap. However someone gave you 1L water. You don't need to take all but to be able to use it you have to. Thus my point is Izuku can only do much before killing himself. That's his 100%. There is also the full power of OfA which is 100%

Comment: @JustPlain please don't forget that in both anime and manga, 100% usually means his "100%" attacks, which explicitly have "100%" in name. Most users here are also using "100%" to specify such attacks, not actual use of 100% of power. For some reason you insist on ignoring this.

Comment: 100% All Might attack is it same as Midori 100%? Of course not bro. Midori must be more weak.

Answer (score 0):

The one time we see Muscular fight in the anime, he's up against Deku, who is substantially less experienced than All Might, cannot use One For All to its full potential yet, and breaks his own limbs when he attacks. But while Muscular has the upper hand for most of the fight, he not only loses, but loses without inflicting *any significant damage* (I recall Deku's only injuries after the fight being cuts, bruises, and the usual self-inflicted broken bones).

All For One fought All Might in the prime of his career, and while he also lost, he *permanently crippled* All Might in the process, destroying a chunk of his internal organs and very nearly killing him. To me, it's no contest: All For One is stronger.

Comment: This question is answered now with the new databook, but I dont want to answer it myself. There you can provide objective data references to your answer